# ChronoForm5 - Joomla || The PayPal API has returned an error

Tags: php, paypal, joomla, chronoforms

I have used chronoform 5 in joomla site and the payment is getting failed. When I enabled log error in paypal it returned following information.

```
The PayPal API has returned an error!
Ack:    
Correlation ID: 
Version:    
Error Number:   
Short Message:  
Long Message:
```

Joomla : 3.7.5

ChronoForm: 5

Payment Processors: PayPal Pro

Answer (score 0):

The payment transaction was a failure due to site lacking https protocol.

PayPal now requires an https connection. Since the payment is handled within the site.